# can't seem to return the value from function, the 2nd function reruns the first function

Tags: python

I have a trivia program that I need to amend to add high scores storing capability. I have amended the code to the requirement but i get an error:

```
line 99, in high_scores
    entry = (score,name)
NameError: name 'score' is not defined*
```

My question is: In the function high_scores, how can I get the variable `score` that I defined in the `main()` function? I have returned the variable score in the main function but I don't know how I can utilize that in my second function that is `high_scores()`.

Here is the code:

```
# Trivia Challenge

# importing modules
import sys, pickle

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    """Open a file, specify a file_name, and mode)"""

    try:
        the_file = open(file_name,mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n", e)
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    """Return next line from the trivia file, formatted."""
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    """Return the next block of data from the trivia file."""
    category = next_line(the_file)
    question = next_line(the_file)

    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))
    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]

    explanation = next_line(the_file)

    points = next_line(the_file)
    if points:
        points = int(points[0])

    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points

def welcome(title):
    """Welcome the player and get his/her name."""
    print("\t\tWelcome to Trivia Challenge!\n")
    print("\t\t", title, "\n")

def main():

    trivia_file = open_file("trivia.txt", "r")
    titlea = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(titlea)
    score = 0
    int(score)

    # get first block
    category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        # ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        print("Points for this question: ", points)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i+1, "=", answers[i])
        answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

        if answer == correct:
            print("\nRight", end=" ")
            score += points
        else:
            print("\nWrong.", end=" ")
        print(explanation)
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block

        category,question,answers,correct,explanation,points = next_block(trivia_file)

    trivia_file.close()

    print("That was the last question!")
    print("You're final score is", score)

    if score > 0:
        print("You have made the high scores list! Congratulations!)")
        high_scores()
    else:
        print("You couldn't make the high scores list. Sorry")
    return score  # returning score so that i can call this function to use the variable in another function

def high_scores():
    global name
    try:
        with open("high_scores.dat", "rb") as f:
            scores = pickle.load(f)
    except EOFError: 
        scores = []
    entry = (score,name)

    scores.append(entry)
    f = open("high_scores.dat", "wb")
    pickle.dump(scores, f)
    f.close()
    print("Your achievement has been successfully saved to the high scores list")        

def display_scores():
    """display scores"""
    try:
        with open("high_scores.dat", "rb") as f:
            scores = pickle.load(f)
        print("\n\nName\t\tScore")
        for entry in scores:
            score, name = entry
            print(name,"\t\t",score)
    except EOFError:
        print("Something unexpected occured...Ending the program")
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
        sys.exit()


response = None


while response != "1":
    print("""
    1. Exit
    2. Play the game
    3. Display high scores
"""
    )
    response = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if response == "2":
        name = input("please enter ur name: ")
        main()
    elif response == "3":
        display_scores()

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Why don't you define `score` outside of the `main` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it as an argument:

```
def high_scores(score):
    ...

...
def main():
    ...
    high_scores(score)
```

Comment: I had completely forgotten that! You saved me!  I was working on it for like 2 hours and i still couldn't figure it on my own.  Thanks a lot Zondo.